# How can i use the For or while loop to fill an array of strings?

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop

When i try this code i don't get any errors or warnings or anything, it just doesn't function properly and i can't figure out why, it shows the strings mixed up or missing characters.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  char arrr[53];
  int i,
  j;
  for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    printf("please enter a string \n");
    scanf("%s", &arrr[i]);
  }

  for (j = 0; j <= 5; j++)
  printf("%s \n", &arrr[j]);

  return 0;
}
```

[image: image showing the issue]

Comment: You have **one** array and you're reading into that array starting from the *second* character slot, and then you're printing the strings from first, second, third, fourth, fifth, sixth character onwards... Please explain what is the **expected behaviour**

Comment: If there are less than 53 characters of input, this program behaves exactly as expected.  That is, it does function properly.   Perhaps there is a disconnect between what it does and what you think it should do.

Comment: Just because something compiles doesn't mean the code will do what you want, or that it won't immediately crash or behave badly. For example, `&arrr[1]` is valid C code and will compile, but it just means "a buffer starting at the second byte of `arr`", so you write to precisely the same spot in that buffer each time.

Comment: You want either an array of arrays or an array of pointers.  Notice the instance of `&arrr[1]` in the first loop.  This reads all strings into the same place, with each one clobbering the one that was previously read, skipping the first character of the array.  It doesn't make sense.

Comment: Is the intent here to read and store 5 arbitrary length C strings taken from standard input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you are trying to do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(void)
{
        char arrr[6][53];
        int i;
        for( i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                if( scanf("%52s", arrr[i]) != 1 ) {
                        break;
                }
        }
        for( int j=0 ; j < i; j++ ) {
                printf("%d: %s\n", j, arrr[j]);
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: can i ask why you used an if statement ? and the utility of it because it solved the problem 
and also why you used %52s instead of %s ? and thank you so much :D

Comment: `%52s` ensures that scanf will not write more than 53 characters to the buffer, which is important because the buffer can only hold 53 char.  If you just use `%s`, you risk a buffer overflow.  You need the `if` statement so that the loop breaks if `scanf` does not read a string (eg, if the end of input is reached, or there is a read error).